# How to preview database generated by Entity Framework migration (code first C#) - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

How can I preview database that I generated by Entity Framework using migrations?
I made models, references then I added migration and updated databes using Package Manager Console. In Solution explorer I have migrations folder and generated database.db.
I need step by step explanation because I am a newbie.
Of course I tried to Google it, but didn't find any step by step tutorial with good explanation for me to understand :(

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644544/can-i-generate-script-of-a-migration-with-ef-code-first-and-net-core) helps